# How to get all data from a particular tab of a Google Sheet and combine into a destination Google Sheet multiple Folders

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google Drive Folder which contains multiple folders inside.I need to combine or Merge all the data from a specific tab of all the sheets inside all the folders of the master folder which contains multiple sheets into a new Google Sheet named Archived which is placed under Archive Folder.

Code tried which does not work is as below.

The script is executing fine without errors but the Destination sheet is not populated with data.

```
   function mergeSheets()
   {
      var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
      while (folders.hasNext())
      {
        var folder = folders.next();
        Logger.log(folder.getName());
      }
      var spreadSheets = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google- 
          apps.spreadsheet");
      while (spreadSheets.hasNext())
      {
        var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
        var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
        for (var y in spreadSheet.getSheets())
         {
            spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet);
         }
      }
     }

     function onOpen()
      {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        var menuItems = [
         { name: 'Merge Release Sheets', functionName: 'mergeSheets' }
           ];
        spreadsheet.addMenu('MergePackages', menuItems);
      }
```

Comment: Where and what is `newSpreadSheet`? Note that your code here never checks any folder for Google Sheets files in your entire Google Drive except for the last one it iterates. You probably want to acquire a specific folder by its name or ID and iterate its subfolders, checking within each for Google Sheets files. Then of course, your current code is set up to copy every tab in each Google Sheet, not just a specific one, so you'll need to fix that too.

Comment: Hello Ruben,Thanks for your response.Can you please share me the code for my requirement.I tried the below and I am getting issue   "Cannot itetrate the next object" by the folowing code

Comment: function mergeSheets() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext())
  {
  var folder = folders.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
  }
var spreadSheets = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
    }
  }      
}

Comment: I have master folder 2018 and I have all the 12 months inside the folder.Inside the months folder I have many google sheets.I have one more folder named Archieve.I have a google sheet named merged packages and I have a tab name AllPacakages in that.I need all the 12 months Google sheet data from a particular sheet packages which is common in all google sheet of the month folders

Comment: All the data from one particular sheet named packages in the all the google sheets of every month folder has to merged to AllPacakages tab of the merged packages of the google sheet of inside the Archieve folder

Comment: **Warning:** this code is designed to apply to **EVERY SPREADSHEET IN EVERY FOLDER** on your Drive. Is this what you really want?

Comment: 1) Delete the first 6 lines of code. 2)`folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");` is invalid; use `DriveApp.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");` 3)`newSpreadSheet` is undefined, probably because you didn't copy this line `var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");` from your original source (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/9XPRMxtwyVM;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQdijsSBLQu0lE-RljlrM2bM9NAuwlMUHAn4bKliEZBFILDIoTs9V126xqsZhE-QVMI_70V3%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false)

Comment: Above all, please, please learn to use Logger.log as well as how to Debug your script.